# How to remove "infinite" while loop to improve MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop

I am implementing a logarithmic quantizer and what I would like to do is to optimize the code as much as possible. The precise point where I would like to make a change is the last `else` statement where the equation to be implemented is:

`q(u) = u_i` if `u_i/(1+step) < u <= u_i/(1-step)`
`u_i = p^(1-i)u_o` for `i=1,2,...`

The parameters `p, step, u_o` are some constants to be chosen.

More information regarding the quantizer can be found at this paper: [Adaptive Backstepping Control of Uncertain Nonlinear Systems with Input Quantization](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6760767).

In order to code a function to implement it in MATLAB, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
function q_u = logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(u,step,u_min)

    u_o = u_min*(1+step);
    p = (1-step)/(1+step);
    
    if u < 0           
        q_u = -logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(-u,step,u_min);            
    elseif ( (u >= 0) && (u <= u_o/(1+step)) )            
        q_u = 0;            
    else            
        i = 1;            
        while (1)                
            u_i = p^(1-i) * u_o;                
            if ( (u > u_i/(1+step)) && (u <= u_i/(1-step)) )                    
                q_u = u_i;
                break;                    
            end                
            i = i + 1;   
        end
    end 
end
```

Now, my issue is to improve the code as much as I can. For example, the `while(1)` loop, which codes the different quantization levels, is something that could probably go away and be replaced. Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well, your problem is that `i` goes to infinity if your condition `( (u > u_i/(1+step)) && (u <= u_i/(1-step)) )` is never true. I don't know much about logarithmic quantization and your link isn't accessible for me.
I'd suggest you to think about how far `i` should go, from 1 to 100,1000,10000,... And then you can use a for-loop instead of the while-loop. Or create a large array which contains values from 1 to 100,1000,1000,... and work with that.

Comment: Given `u` and `step` you can simply calculate the minimum and maximum acceptable values of `ui`, and from that you can directly calculate your minimum and maximum acceptable value of `i` knowing `p`. Then you take the (I assume) first integer in that range (`ceil(i_min)` for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `u_min>0` and `0<p<1`, you can simplify `(u > u_i/(1+step)) && (u <= u_i/(1-step))` to:

```
u/u_min > p^(1-i) && p^-i >= u/u_min
```

Which since `log` is monotonic, simplifies to

```
-log(u/u_min)/log(p) > i-1 && i >= -log(u/u_min)/log(p)
```

Which makes the while loop equivalent to simply

```
i = floor(-log(u/u_min)/log(p));
q_u = p^(1-i) * u_o;
```

Furthermore, `(u >= 0)` in the `elseif` branch is always true, and you probably can get rid of the `u<0` test, by replacing `u` by `abs(u)` at the right places.