# Specific C++ code section increases code execution time

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, eigen

I have written the following piece in order to test a function, which implements a logarithmic hysteretic quantizer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <math.h>

double logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(double u, double u_prev, double delta, double u_min);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Eigen::MatrixXd control_signal = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(7,1);
    double delta = 0.1765;
    double u_min = 0.01;

    double i = 0.0;

    while (i >= -20.0) {
    
        std::cout << "FOR LOOP" << std::endl;
    
        control_signal << logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(i, control_signal(0,0), delta, u_min),
                          logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(i, control_signal(1,0), delta, u_min),
                          logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(i, control_signal(2,0), delta, u_min),
                          logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(i, control_signal(3,0), delta, u_min),
                          logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(i, control_signal(4,0), delta, u_min),
                          logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(i, control_signal(5,0), delta, u_min), 
                          logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(i, control_signal(6,0), delta, u_min);
    
        std::cout << control_signal << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    
        i = i - 0.001;
    
        }
   return 0;
}

double logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(double u, double u_prev, double delta, double u_min) 
{

    double u_i = 0.0;
    double u_i_next = 0.0;
    double p = (1.0-delta)/(1.0+delta);

    /* For Debugging Purposes */
    std::cout << "INSIDE" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "U is: " << u << std::endl;
    std::cout << "U_PREV is: " << u_prev << std::endl;

    if (u < 0.0) {
        return -logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(-u, u_prev, delta, u_min);
    } else if (((u >= 0.0) && (u <= u_min/(1.0+delta))) || ((u < u_min) && (u > u_min/(1.0+delta)))) {
        std::cout << "DEAD ZONE" << std::endl;
        double w = 0.0;
        return w;
    
    } else {
    
        int i = 1;
    
        while(1) {
        
            u_i = pow(p,(1-i))*u_min;
            u_i_next = pow(p,(1-(i+1)))*u_min;
        
            if ( ((u > u_i/(1.0+delta)) && (u <= u_i) && (u_prev >= u_i)) || ((u < u_i/(1.0-delta)) && (u_i <= u) && (u_prev <= u_i)) ) {
            
                return u_i;
            
            } else if ( ((u_i < u) && (u <= u_i/(1.0-delta)) && (u_prev >= u_i*(1.0+delta))) || ((u_i/(1.0-delta) <= u) && (u <= u_i_next) && (u_prev <= u_i*(1+delta))) ) {
            
                return u_i*(1.0+delta);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing the following issue. When the `else if` statement (the one for the `DEAD ZONE`) is executed many times until the value gets out of the dead zone, the code executes somewhat slowly in the beggining while when this `else if` statement isn't executed many times (when for example `i = i - 1.0` instead of `i = i - 0.001`) the code is executed in a blink of an eye. I tried using breakpoints at this section in order to check if a particular instruction takes some time but this doesn't seem to be the case. Profiling the code also gave me a general idea of how much time the `logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer()` function takes but this doesn't really help me to understand what's going on. Could anyone give me insight of what's going on at this section of the code ?

P.S.: I am running the code at Xcode 12.4.

Comment: `std::cout << "DEAD ZONE" << std::endl;` is super slow. `std::cout << "DEAD ZONE\n";` is just slow. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Even if I comment the whole `std::cout << "DEAD ZONE" << std::endl;` line there isn't much of a change.

Comment: The `while` loop looks like it could be the culprit. How many iterations does that do in total when you run your program?

Comment: Just used a global counter to measure it. The while loop runs `3284029` times. That's a lot I think but this is how the logarithmic quantizer is working. I have to loop until I found the right interval for the value to be quantized.

Comment: It is hard to say what you want to achieve. You use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator in `control_signal << ` line, which means: "calculate every expression, but take only the last value" (in that case `logarithmic_hysteretic_quantizer(i, control_signal(6,0), delta, u_min)`. On the other hand: did you enable compiler optimization? It is pointless to analyze a program in term of performance, when you are not using optimizations

Comment: And when I remove every `cout` call then the program takes `0.143 s` to run, which a pretty small number. I have compiled a program with  `clang++ -O3 -march=native` flags, which enable high optimization as well as optimizations related to your specific CPU

Comment: And with addition of the dangerous `-ffast-math` flag (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do) I have achieved a `0.028 s` time

Comment: @Slay, the comma-operator in this case is overloaded: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html#title0 -- but I agree that benchmarking code with `std::cout` inside is pointless ...

Comment: You can very likely replace the `while`-loop by solving the inequations for `u_i` and `u_i_next` and compute `i` using `log`. Due to the many branches and forced lazy-evaluation of `&&` and `||` your code may also suffer from failed branch-predictions.

Comment: Any reason you inserted many more tests compared to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075396/? (I will not analyze if any of these conditions actually make a difference ...)